# how to store values elements of datasets into different arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays

I have a convoluted plan for a program.

I would like to have datasets of three values be stored in different arrays, i.e the first value be stored in the first array, the second value in the second array and the third in the third array.

For example:

```
"How often would you like to repeat the program"
2
"Enter the first value:"
1
"Enter the second value:"
2
"Enter the third value:"
3
"Enter the first value:"
4
"Enter the second value:"
5
"Enter the third value:"
6
```

The output should be something like this

```
a_arr = [1 4]
b_arr = [2 5]
c_arr = [3 6]
```

I have come up with this code but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 255
//validation function
int a_arr[MAX_SIZE]; // Declare an array of MAX_SIZE
int b_arr[MAX_SIZE]; // Declare an array of MAX_SIZE
int c_arr[MAX_SIZE]; // Declare an array of MAX_SIZE
int i;
int checkInput0(void);
float checkInput1(void);
float checkInput2(void);
float checkInput3(void);
a_arr[] = checkInput1;
b_arr[] = checkInput2;
c_arr[] = checkInput3;

int main()
{
    int repeats = 0, counter = 0;
    //Amount of triangles
    repeats = checkInput0();

    // create arrays for all values
    do {
        i = counter;
        for(i=0; i<repeats; i++)
        {
            scanf("%f", &a_arr[i]);
        }
        for(i=0; i<repeats; i++)
        {
            scanf("%f", &b_arr[i]);
        }
        for(i=0; i<repeats; i++)
        {
            scanf("%f", &c_arr[i]);
        }

        counter++;
    }while(counter < repeats);

    do {
        printf("%f\n",a_arr );
        printf("%f\n",b_arr );
        printf("%f\n",c_arr );
        counter++;
    }while(counter < repeats);

    return 0;
}

// Validate Value of a
float checkInput1(void){
    float option1,check1;
    char c;

    do{
        printf("Enter the first side of the triangle");

        if(scanf("%f%c",&option1,&c) == 0 || c != '\n') {
            while((check1 = getchar()) != 0 && check1 != '\n' && check1 != EOF);
            printf("\t[ERR] Invalid number for the triplet.\n");
        }else {
            break;
        }
    }while(1);
    // printf("returning the value of option, which is %f", option);
    return option1;
}

// Validate Value of b
float checkInput2(void){
    float option2,check2;
    char c;

    do{
        printf("Enter the second side of the triangle");

        if(scanf("%f%c",&option2,&c) == 0 || c != '\n'){
            while((check2 = getchar()) != 0 && check2 != '\n' && check2 != EOF);
            printf("\t[ERR] Invalid number for the triplet.\n");
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }while(1);
  //printf("returning the value of option, which is %f", option2);
    return option2;
}

// Validate Value of c
float checkInput3(void){
    float option3,check3;
    char c;

    do{
        printf("Enter the third side of the triangle");

        if(scanf("%f%c",&option3,&c) == 0 || c != '\n'){
            while((check3 = getchar()) != 0 && check3 != '\n' && check3 != EOF);
            printf("\t[ERR] Invalid number for the triplet.\n");
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }while(1);
    // printf("returning the value of option, which is %f", option);
    return option3;
}
```

Note: the functions are there for validation such that the input is a number.

All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `a_arr[] = checkInput1;`...in file scope???

Comment: What do you think `a_arr[] = checkInput1;` does?

Comment: well what I wanted to do was to somehow store the value that checkInput returns into a_arr[]

Comment: Can't find the definition of `checkInput0()`.

Comment: I forgot to add checkInput(0): here it is int checkInput0(void){
    float option0,check0;
    char c;
    
    do{
       printf("Enter the amount of triangles you want to check: \n");
        
        if(scanf("%f%c",&option0,&c) == 0 || c != '\n'){
            while((check0 = getchar()) != 0 && check0 != '\n' && check0 != EOF);
            printf("[ERR] Invalid number of triangles.\n");
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }while(1);
    // printf("returning the value of option, which is %f", option);
    return option0;
}

Comment: @GehteuchNixan Add to post, not comment. Click [edit] for edit post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have complicated this.
You can do something like this.

```
printf("How many...");
scanf("%d", &num);  //num is the user input

int i;
for(i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    printf("enter first number");
    a_arr[i] = checkInput1();
    printf("enter first number");
    b_arr[i] = checkInput2();
    printf("enter first number");
    c_arr[i] = checkInput3();
}
```

Comment: didnt seem to find any reason of using checkinput methods / functions, simple scanf might do

Comment: @ShreyanMehta yes i agree. I just wrote this answer in accord to OP's code hoping it would somehow make the `main()` more readable. And also these functions don't hurt. Though just one function could have done the work of all three!

Answer (score 0):

The last 3 declarations before main have no sense.

Answering the question, the pseudocode is simple. You have 3 arrays, so when the iterator of scans reach i = 3n-1, being n= 0,1,2,3,4..., then the index is increased.

E.g., scanf 0, 1 and 2 are all saved in index 0 of the respective array (2 = 3n-1, n being 1); scanf 3,4 and 5 are all saved in index 1 of the respective array (5 = 3n-1, n being 2) and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wasting lot of memory doing this statically, simple malloc can save lot of memory and time(speed of execution i meant)

```
printf("How many...");
scanf("%d", &num);  //num is the user input


int * a_arr = (int *)malloc( num * sizeof(int));
int * b_arr = (int *)malloc( num * sizeof(int));
int * c_arr = (int *)malloc( num * sizeof(int));
int count;
for(count=0; count<num; count++)
{
    printf("enter first number");
    scanf("%d",a_arr[count]);
    printf("enter first number");
    scanf("%d",b_arr[count]);
    printf("enter first number");
    scanf("%d",c_arr[count]);
}
//print or whatever you wanna do processing on it
```

Comment: `i` is uninitialized. And you are using that in `malloc()`. Why? well what does `i` signify in your code in the first place??

Comment: @AditiRawat well good noticed, just edited it again, thanks for pointing that out